# Add user (personal) dictionary to Android stock keyboard for unsupported languages

Tags: keyboard, dictionary, text-prediction

I am sure many people have noticed that in the stock keyboard (Android 4.2 in my case) has more language layouts than it supports predicting. For many languages a dictionary / corpus is missing.

So since it is rather easy to build a corpus, I wanted to add my own dictionary for some languages which have no official dictionary. But I cannot find any solution. Has this been achieved before?

Note: *Adding the words 1 by 1 is not a solution*. :-)

If there was a solution, many people would be helped I guess. Thanks for any help and hint given!